In a Ghidra Loader in Java, how can I set the types of symbols or at addresses?
I'm writing a bunch of Ghidra Loaders for retro platforms.
I know how to use SymbolTable createLabel() and addExternalEntryPoint() but sometimes I know the types of certain fields, symbols, or addresses too.
So far I can't find how to add types from Java. For now I'm only thinking about basic data types like byte, word, dword, if that makes a difference.

I managed to figure it out by a combination of guesswork, fumbling around, and searching the Ghidra source on GitHub:
The term used by Ghidra is DataType and data types are set via the Listing, which you can obtain in your Loader's load() method:
Listing listing = program.getListing();

And you can then set built-in types like so:
listing.createData(address, UnsignedShortDataType.dataType);
listing.createData(address, PascalStringDataType.dataType);

If you haven't used addresses before, you typically get them like this:
AddressSpace addressSpace = program.getAddressFactory().getDefaultAddressSpace();
Address loadAddress = addressSpace.getAddress(0x30000);

By the way, strings and arrays are a little different:
listing.createData(address, new StringDataType(), 2);
listing.createData(address.add(2), new ArrayDataType(UnsignedIntegerDataType.dataType, 4));

